# Writing a Profiler query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am writing a query to simulate the Sql Server Profiler, my version is Sql Server 2008 I don't have Sql Profiler and I need it, at this moment I got this Query:

```
Use master
Go

Alter procedure dbo.NS_sp_profilerQuery
    @dbName sysname='',
    @userName sysname=Null,
    @hostName sysname=Null
As
Begin
    --Step 1. Declaration of variables.
    Declare @idDb Int=DB_ID(@dbName);
    Declare @Query Nvarchar(Max);

    --Step 2. SETTING THE query.
    Select @Query = N'Select '+
    N'idProceso=syp.spid,basedatos=DB_NAME(syp.dbid),usuario=syp.loginame,cpu,hostname,espera=lastwaittype,[bloqueadoPor]=blocked,Query=(Select text from ::fn_get_sql(syp.sql_handle)) '+
    N'From master.dbo.sysprocesses syp '+
    N'Where 1=1 '+
    (case when @idDb is null then '' else 'and syp.dbid='+Ltrim(Rtrim(Str(@idDb))) end)+
    (case when @userName is null then '' else ' and Ltrim(Rtrim(syp.loginame))='+Quotename(Ltrim(Rtrim(@userName)),Char(39)) end)+
    (case when @hostName is null then '' else ' and Ltrim(Rtrim(syp.hostname))='+Quotename(Ltrim(Rtrim(@hostName)),Char(39)) end);

    --Step 3. Query and return data.
    Exec(@Query);
End
Go
```

This query captures everything in one point, my question is : 
What is the best way to capture everything that happens in a long time?, Making a loop?
What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Query solved my need, it works on 99% times, I took snapshots to the dbo.sysprocesses.

```
Use master
Go

Alter procedure dbo.NS_sp_profilerQuery
    @dbName sysname='',
    @userName sysname=Null,
    @hostName sysname=Null,
    @Seconds int
As
Begin

    Declare @SnapShots Table(
    idProceso int,
    idThread int,
    basedatos sysname, 
    usuario sysname, 
    cpu int, 
    hostname sysname, 
    espera sysname, 
    bloqueadoPor int, 
    Query Nvarchar(Max)
);

Declare @Profiler Table(
    idProceso int,
    idThread int,
    basedatos sysname, 
    usuario sysname, 
    cpu int, 
    hostname sysname, 
    espera sysname, 
    bloqueadoPor int, 
    Query Nvarchar(Max)
);

--Paso 1. Declaración de variables.
Declare @idDb Int=DB_ID(@dbName);
Declare @Query Nvarchar(Max);
Declare @HoraFinal Datetime=DateAdd(Second,@Seconds,Getdate());

While Getdate()<=@HoraFinal
Begin
    --Paso 2. Seteo de consulta.
    Select @Query = N'Select '+
    N'idProceso=syp.spid,idThread=syp.kpid,basedatos=DB_NAME(syp.dbid),usuario=syp.loginame,cpu,hostname,espera=lastwaittype,[bloqueadoPor]=blocked,Query=(Select text from ::fn_get_sql(syp.sql_handle)) '+
    N'From master.dbo.sysprocesses syp '+
    N'Where 1=1 '+
    (case when @idDb is null then '' else 'and syp.dbid='+Ltrim(Rtrim(Str(@idDb))) end)+
    (case when @userName is null then '' else ' and Ltrim(Rtrim(syp.loginame))='+Quotename(Ltrim(Rtrim(@userName)),Char(39)) end)+
    (case when @hostName is null then '' else ' and Ltrim(Rtrim(syp.hostname))='+Quotename(Ltrim(Rtrim(@hostName)),Char(39)) end);

    --Paso 3. Consulta y retorno de datos.
    Insert Into @SnapShots(idProceso,idThread,basedatos,usuario,cpu,hostname,espera,bloqueadoPor,Query)
    Exec(@Query);

    Insert Into @Profiler(idProceso,idThread,basedatos,usuario,cpu,hostname,espera,bloqueadoPor,Query)
    Select 
        sna.idProceso,sna.idThread,sna.basedatos,sna.usuario,sna.cpu,sna.hostname,sna.espera,sna.bloqueadoPor,sna.Query 
    From @SnapShots sna
    Left Join @Profiler pro
        On (sna.idProceso=pro.idProceso and sna.idThread=pro.idThread)
    Where pro.idProceso is null;

    Delete From @SnapShots;
End

Select 
    idProceso,idThread,basedatos,usuario,cpu,hostname,espera,bloqueadoPor,Query
From @Profiler;

End
Go
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not really possible to simulate the profiler with a single query like that. You will just get snapshots of currently running queries. Maybe that is good enough for you if you want to see queries that takes a long time to run, but in that case I would rather recommend that you take a look at the dmv sys.dm_exec_query_stats. With this you can examine which queries take up lot of resources or time.

Example, including query plans:

```
-- List top 100 queries that has the highest average logical reads
select top (100) *
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
  cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) p
order by cast(qs.total_logical_reads as float) / qs.execution_count desc;
```

There are many interesting columns to sort on.

If you really want to capture all executed queries you should look into extended events. You can log the queries you want to for example a file or ring buffer that you can examine later. There is a bit of work involved into setting it up but the official sql server documentation has good information on how to do it.